# Sticky "back to top" button showing on page load, before scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I followed a tutorial to get a sticky "back to top" button that would appear once you scroll down. For some reason it's displaying when you're at the top of the page after the page first loads. If you scroll down, then all the way back up, it disappears (as it should). But initially it isn't behaving properly. Any idea?

Here's the live page I'm using it on, you can see it in the bottom right corner here: http://willryan.us

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="go-top" style="display: inline;">Back to top</a>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Show or hide the sticky footer button
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                    $('.go-top').fadeIn(500);
                } else {
                    $('.go-top').fadeOut(300);
                }
            });

            // Animate the scroll to top
            $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
            })
        });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.go-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0.75em;
    right: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.go-top:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You're loading the element with `display:inline`, change that to `display:none` and it wont be there when you first load

Comment: Are you talking about the ".go-top" class? That does have display:none.

EDIT: Ahh, you're talking about the html. I'll try that now, thanks.

Comment: Your HTML has an inline style that says `display:inline` - Either make your style sheet say `display:none !important;` or change your inline style to the same.

Comment: @WillRyan He is talking about the very first line - <a>

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Weird... the tutorial specifically had that HTML chunk with display:inline.

Comment: my answer is below ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your HTML from

```
<a href="#" class="go-top" style="display: inline;">Back to top</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" class="go-top" style="display: none;">Back to top</a>
```

This will initially hide your button until you scroll.

Answer (score 6):

It's displaying because you haven't fired a scroll event yet to make that logic get run to hide/show it

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function checkPosition() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('.go-top').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('.go-top').fadeOut(300);
            }
        }
        // Show or hide the sticky footer button
        $(window).scroll(checkPosition);

        // Animate the scroll to top
        $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
        })

        checkPosition();
    });
</script>
```

This new refactor will fire `checkPosition` at least once on page load, to make sure the button is faded out. An alternative solution would be to set `display: none;` in the CSS on the element, so it's hidden by default, then only shown by the javascript later

Comment: My understanding was that this code would have it hidden by default, then show it once you scroll.

Comment: Yep, it's not though, because the part that hides it is only run when you start scrolling. You need to run that 'position' check at least once at the page load. See my alternative solution at the bottom, as well.

Comment: This will also make it `fadeOut` when you load.  So you will SEE it fade out on load

Comment: Yep, good point. The CSS/inline display: none options are better

Answer (score 1):

I did as user ntgCleaner said and change the "display:inline" in the html to "display:none" and it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: whoops, didn't see your other comment until now, just your original comment on my post. just chose your's as the correct answer, thanks again!

Comment: Anytime! glad I could help